# Struts 2 Validation failing when Action class sits in a separate jar file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, struts

I have a maven multi-module project.

```
project-services (service layer..above the dao layer)
project-controller (My Action classes sits in this module)
project-web (all jsps, view artificats)
```

The issue is I have a valid DefaultProjectsAction-validation.xml in the package with DefaultProjectsAction.java as well as the properties file.

All these modules, when the war file is deployed will be in /WEB-INF/lib. I use in struts.xml the default package. All files are correctly set-up. Spellings errors on the the file names checked properly. Will my struts validations work if the validation xml files are in a seperate jar. I read somewhere where they say it should be in WEB-INF/classes/. Is this the reason why my struts form can't be validated?

Comment: Validation files *should* be searched for on the class path, although I've never tried it. If you create a small github project that re-creates just the problem I'll take a look. Separating actions from the web module seems a bit strange, unless you're genuinely using the controllers outside of the web.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The reason why action classes sits separately is because I am using existing view artifacts and the controllers (in this case in Struts 2) was told to put them in their own module. It's been two days now trying to work around the problem. The docs does not say much. But surely in the <ActionName>-validation.xml sits in the same package with the Action they are both in the classpath. I am thinking of using global validations which i will put directly in /WEB-INF/classes/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok it's exactly 48 hours since I started looking at this problem and ladies and gentlemen the solution has been found.

Putting struts 2 action classes on a seperate module and validation set-up has to go like this.

```
project-controller (will have action classes for Struts 2 in this case)
 - com.pack.UserAction.java
```

The solution is to create a source folder src/main/resources/com/pack (Maven project) in project-web module and put UserAction-validation.xml in there. Like this

```
project-web (views, jsps, properties files and set-up files)
 - src/main/resources/com/pack/UserAction-validation.xml
```

The file will be copied to /WEB-INF/classes/com/pack (The action class package should form the path) and on building the project